# How can I link my Spacechem profiles between Linux and Windows?

Tags: linux, spacechem

I dualboot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Since SpaceChem is one of the few HIB games coming in .deb format, I decided to install it on Ubuntu as well.

Now, for Minecraft what I did was create a symbolic link between `~/.minecraft/saves` and `/media/blah/Users/badp/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/saves`, so that both installs share levels.

How can I do the same with SpaceChem?

Comment: @dawmail333 Accepting your own answer is both a tedious process (gotta wait two days) and a purely cosmetical one

Comment: Maybe so, but it helps keep the site tidy, and is great for anyone else who drops in, particularly if they're unfamiliar with this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The folders that need linking are: (for Windows)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Zachtronics Industries\SpaceChem
```

...and: (for Linux and OS X)

```
~/.local/share/Zachtronics Industries/SpaceChem
```

Comment: Would you happen to know where the Mac folder is, too?

Comment: @fbrereto I'd be surprised if it wasn't the same path as Linux, given that it's a Mono app.

Comment: badp: you are correct; the path is the same on the Mac. Thanks!